# How to add smooth low shadow on UIToolBar frame and line separator between UIToolBarItems

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I am trying to create an UIToolBar looks like image-1 , however output of my operations did occur as image-2. How could I add a shadow layer of UIToolBar and separator between its Items ?

I did find this question for separator but there no answer in there -> [Separator between toolbar items in UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180537/separator-between-toolbar-items-in-uitoolbar)

[image: IMAGE-1]

[image: IMAGE-2]

Comment: could you show us a piece of code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: @dirtydanee yes of course I could share , but torpillo did suggest good library I think , I am trying to use now . If I get negative issue about library , of course I am going to share :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this apple doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIToolbar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIToolbar

Also there is a library option on GitHub:
https://github.com/iosphere/ISHHoverBar

**EDIT:**

This is how you use the lib (ViewDidLoad)

```
UIBarButtonItem *mapBarButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton      buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; 
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleOrientation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
UIBarButtonItem *infoBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton]; 
[self.hoverbar setItems:@[mapBarButton, infoBarButton]];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am working on library that you gave called as ISHHoverBar , however I cannot find any tutorial or trial about it. Could you have ?

Comment: I downloaded the sample app..seems helpful.

Comment: Thank you, When I convert it swift I am going to share here :)

Comment: @torpillo when I wrote this `let x = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)
        
        floatingButton.items?.append(x)
        ` , nothing gonna be added on floating Button. Of course I linked to floatingButton as `@IBOutlet weak var floatingButton: ISHHoverBar!
`

Comment: I did solve problem because it comes along nil value that's okey. But when I use auto layout on Interface Builder , view was going to be large width.. How could I from escape this ?

Comment: actually it's looks like bug. Because when I try to it with leading constraint it's going to be large width than accepted.Trailing constraint works as accepted... :)

Comment: Happy to hear that you solved it, keep me on track for this if you need something (name changed from torpillo to George_v)

Comment: do you have any idea about this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506333/how-to-change-mkusertrackingbarbuttonitem-style